# AWS Lambda container reuse conflicts with SFTP connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sftp

I have a lambda function that uses `ssh2-sftp-client` library to transfer files to an SFTP server. I want to invoke this function multiple times at the same time. What happens is since they get passed on to the same container because of Lambda's container reuse, there's a conflict when the second invocation tries to connect to SFTP since a connection has already been made by the first one. I can set the function to just use the same connection but the problem will arise when to end it. Are there other ways to run simultaneously without affecting each other's run? Or is this use case not fit for lambda? Is it better to use Fargate for this one even if it's just a simple function?

Comment: Presumably it's not that running simultaneously is a problem (because you're not reusing an execution environment in that scenario), it's running consecutively that's the problem because you don't know when a given environment will be recycled. Is there an issue if you simply create the SFTP connection within the Lambda function handler, then close it before exiting?

Comment: Hi @jarmod. I am currently creating and ending the connection. My assumption is since the lambda function are using the same container, when the first invocation ends the connection, it will also stop the connection of the other invocation after it.

Comment: Let me know, if I am missing something. Do you mean lambda functions when using the same container waits for each invocation to finish before running the next one?

Comment: If one instance of a Lambda invocation is in progress then that container environment cannot be re-used concurrently. The Lambda service will either cold-start a new environment or it will wait for the current invocation to complete before it reuses it (depending on your config, account limits, service availability etc.)

Comment: @jarmod, ohh thank you. I was not aware that's how it works. I have to check my cde. I might block the end function which caused the existing connection error. Big help. Thanks.